# Bootbox confirm inputType select, is there a way to dynamically populate inputOptions?

Tags: javascript, bootbox

My web UI has a function that searches for potential paths to the project source, and this can result in multiple options. I'm trying to collect them, and then throw up a bootbox.confirm with inputType select so that the user can select the correct path. I want to be able to pass the dynamic list of paths to the bootbox though, and not hard code them. For example:

```
    $scope.promptSelectSourcepath = function(finalResult) {
    bootbox.prompt({
        size: "medium",
        message: "Please select your project sourcepath from the following list",
        inputType: 'select',
        inputOptions: [
            {
                text: 'text from the dynamic array',
                value: 'value from the dynamic array',
            }
        ],
```

I guess I'm looking for some type of ng-repeat functionality within the confirmation bootbox. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, while it isn't pretty I did figure out a way to do this by having the REST controller pass back an ArrayList of HashMaps - bootbox was able to interpret that when I set the inputOptions field to the returned array.